# Another "invalid initialization of reference of type" error

Tags: c++, reference, constants

I have container in my class like this:

```
protected:
std::map<const AAA*, std::set<BBB*> > conn;
```

Both of the following getter functions works just fine:

```
std::map<const AAA*, std::set<BBB*> > & getConnectors()       {return connectors;}
std::map<const AAA*, std::set<BBB*> >   getConnectors() const {return connectors;}
```

but &  and const together, Nope.Gives error:

```
std::map<const AAA*, std::set<BBB*> > & getConnectors() const {return connectors;} //error
```

Error is:

```
/home.../Multi.hpp:65:108: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘std::map<const AAA*, std::set<BBB*> >&’ from expression of type ‘const std::map<const AAA*, std::set<BBB*> >’
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/SimMobility.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 1
```

why I am getting this and How may I solve it please

thank you

Comment: Read the error message! In a `const` method, the `this` pointer and the members are treated as `const`, you cannot return a non-`const` reference to a `const` object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This doesn't work because **from a `const` method all members** (besides `mutable`) **should be treated as if they are `const` themselves**.

This means that not only you can't modify them from that method, but also you can't point to them with a pointer to non-const or form a reference to non-const.

Hence, use:

```
      std::map<Foo, Bar> & GetConnectors();
const std::map<Foo, Bar> & GetConnectors() const;
```

Answer (score 1):

the last one should be written as

```
const std::map<const AAA*, std::set<BBB*> > & getConnectors() const {return connectors;}
```