# C++ function that accepts parametrized type including subtypes

Tags: c++, templates, openfoam

The OpenFOAM library defines two types, `volMesh` and `surfaceMesh`, both of which inherit from `GeoMesh<fvMesh>`.  I want to define a function that accepts an argument:

```
void foo(GeometricField<vector, fvsPatchField, GeoMesh<fvMesh> >& field) { ... }
```

However, g++ gives the error "invalid initialization of reference type" when I try to call the function:

```
// surfaceVectorField is a typedef GeometricField<vector, fvsPatchField, surfaceMesh>
surfaceVectorField Uf( /* initialisation arguments */ ); 
foo(Uf);
```

Coming from a Java background, this problem seems similar to forgetting to use a declaration such as

```
void foo(GeometricField<vector, fvsPatchField, ? extends GeoMesh<fvMesh>> field) { ... }
```

I need to avoid C++11-specific features if possible.

Comment: can you add a bit more code, namely an example of how you try to call your function?

Comment: is the error from the function call to `foo()` or the variable definition of `Uf`?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9285627/is-it-possible-to-pass-derived-classes-by-reference-to-a-function-taking-base-cl

Comment: maybe it cannot convert your surfaceMesh parameter to `GeoMesh<fvMesh>`, or the whole construct to the reference to the correct complex type.

Comment: @RichardChambers: The error is from the call to `foo()`

Comment: Try explicitly converting surfaceMesh to `GeoMesh<fvMesh>` when initializing surfaceVectorField.

Comment: Do you inherit it privately? If yes, it cannot access base in the function call

Comment: @Kostya: No, for example, `surfaceMesh` declaration starts like this: `class surfaceMesh : public GeoMesh<fvMesh>`

Comment: Can you make the function a template?  `template <typename T> void foo(GeometricField<vector, fvsPatchField, T>& field) { ... }`

Comment: Could there be a `const` conflict since the function prototype is not `const`?  [Another "invalid initialization of reference of type" error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11609965/another-invalid-initialization-of-reference-of-type-error) or [g++ gives error: invalid initialization of reference of type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17453738/g-gives-error-invalid-initialization-of-reference-of-type-char-from-expre)

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem in your function declaration is that the type of the argument can not be resolved. That means that the specilization of the template class can not be deduced if you give the base class as a template parameter.

The argument you hope to take in is an instance of the template class GeometricField. Further, the name of the class template is not a type. Indicating that a function definition `foo(GeometricField& field);` is not possible.

If you want the function to accept geometric fields from both surface and volumetric mesh types you need to make it a template function or overload it. First template:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(GeometricField<vector, fvsPatchField, T>& field) {}
```

or just

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T& field) {}
```

which ever better suits what you do in the function. Notice also that if the function is going to be reused, you need to take care of the cases when the argument is not what you expect.

Overloading:

```
void foo(surfaceVectorField& field);
void foo(volVectorField& field);
```

Both solutions should get you there.